# Kinematic Modelling with clockwise angles defined as positive

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics

It seems when modeling a system for which an clockwise angles is defined as positive, the resulting equations become wrong.
For example :

In the picture below $\theta_x$, the orientation of the ball, is measured positive in clockwise rotation around the $x$ axis.
When I want to compute the velocity $v_a$ of the point on the ball touching the ground it should be 0.

However:

$
v_a = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \dot{\theta_x}*r_s\\ 0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \dot{\theta_x}\\0 \\0 \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\ 0 \\ -r_s
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2*r_s*\dot{\theta_x} \\0 \end{bmatrix}
$

Is there a mistake in my reasoning ?

[image: source:https://essay.utwente.nl/65559/1/vanderBlonk_MSc_EEMCS.pdf, p10]

Comment: How are you getting a scalar from the addition of two vectors?

Comment: @probably_someone , thanks I corrected it. I accidently left the other entries out, since they are zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the definition of the angular velocity vector is

$$\vec{\omega} = \frac{\vec{r}\times\vec{v}}{r^2}$$

When you change which direction corresponds to positive rotation, you are also changing the direction that $\vec{\omega}$ points relative to the $z$-axis. To be consistent, if you haven't changed which direction the $z$-axis points on your diagrams, you must instead *change the definition of the cross product* to use the "left-hand rule" instead of the right-hand rule, which gives you the result of the opposite sign.

Comment: I assume in your example $\vec{\omega}$ describes a rotation around the $z$-axis ?

Comment: @ganto Yes, it does.